How to input to attributes which is also objects from another class?
I have this class xOy
    public class xOy {
        float x;
        float y;
        public void input(){  
           System.out.println("input infor");  
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
           this.x = sc.nextFloat();  
           this.y = sc.nextFloat();  
    }
}

And another class triangle
    public class Triangle extends xOy{  
        xOy point1;  
        xOy point2;  
        xOy point3;
    
}

I want to let user input x and y value of each point in Triangle class in console.
I expect point1.x = 3, point1.y = 5, similar to other points.

Since input () is an instance method, you need to instantiate x0y Objects to invoke that method: x0y point1 = new x0y (0); Then, you can invoke using the name of an instance: point1.input (); Also, you (probably) do not want Triangle to extend x0y.  It looks like you want Triangle HAS A x0y  (actually 3 of them).  You don't want to compound that with an unnecessary IS A.

It does not make much sense to extend a class have the subclass contain instances of the parent.

Create an instance of Triangle class. Then for each of these xOy point, instantiate
them and call input() method. Also, why is Triangle extending xOy?

your class Triangle not need to extends xOy,you just need like this
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Triangle triangle=new Triangle();
    /*
      this can make a constructor for Triangle to do
     */
triangle.point1=new xOy();
triangle.point2=new xOy();
triangle.point3=new xOy();

triangle.point1.input();
triangle.point2.input();
triangle.point3.input();

System.out.println(triangle.point1);
System.out.println(triangle.point2);
System.out.println(triangle.point3);
}
static class xOy{
    float x;
    float y;
    public void input(){
        System.out.println("input infor");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.x = sc.nextFloat();
        this.y = sc.nextFloat();
    }
}
static class Triangle{
    xOy point1;
    xOy point2;
    xOy point3;
}


That is not really the way to do it.  You should have a constructor to create a class with values when it is created and setters to assign values to a non initialized class or to change the values of the class.
import java.util.Scanner;

class XOy {
    private float x;
    private float y;
    
    public XOy() {}
    
    public XOy(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(float y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "x = " + x + "y = " + y;
    }
}
      
class Triangle extends XOy {  
    public Triangle() {}
    public Triangle(float x, float y) {
        super(x,y);
    }
}
public class DemoConstructor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle t1 = new Triangle(10f,20f);
        System.out.println(t1.getX()); // uses parent getters
        System.out.println(t1.getY());
        
        // or
        Triangle t2 = new Triangle();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter x and y");
        float x = s.nextFloat();
        float y = s.nextFloat();
        t2.setX(x); // uses parent setters
        t2.setY(y);
        System.out.println(t2); // parent toString
    }
}

Sample input and output
10.0
20.0
Enter x and y
33
93
x = 33.0y = 93.0

You can find more details about the above in the Java Tutorials

I think he's trying to have 3 locations(x,y) in Triangle class as it'd have 3 corners. Won't it be better to not extend xOy?

@sittsering  You could be correct.  All I have to go on is what the OP posted.

@sittsering you are correct, that's what I want.

@danghoang Then you need to edit your question and explain exactly what you want.  Also, please explain why you are subclassing Triangle with oXo?
